# MySQL and Python: Avoiding duplicate entries in mysql table

Tags: python, mysql

I'm writing a python script that accesses data from a website called octopart and inserts that data into a MySQL table.  The end goal is this:

1. Script runs once or twice a day querying octopart with a custom API
2. Data is collected from octopart and parsed into a useful format using json
3. Headers and values that are selected from the data are inserted into the MySQL table
4. (As the script continues to run) Script updates certain entries of the table that are not equal to new entries from octopart without hitting a duplicate entry sql error.

I have included the code that should be performing (4.) below.  I am still getting a 1062 Duplicate Entry error.  Any advice?

**VARIABLES:**

- mylisth: the list of headers drawn from the octopart data
- mylistv: the list of values that correspond to each of the headers
- value['display_value']: the next value to be added to mylistv for each chunk of data

  ```
  heads = ','.join(str(i) for i in mylisth)

  #create string input of %s corresponding to number of entries in mylisth
  placelst = ['%s' for i in mylisth]
  placestr = ','.join(str(i) for i in placelst)

  #add_capacitor -> SQL query line // data_capacitor -> values to be inserted using query line
  duplicate_check = ("SELECT * FROM capacitors")    
  add_capacitor = ("INSERT INTO capacitors ("+heads+") VALUES ("+placestr+")")
  replace_capacitor = ("REPLACE INTO capacitors ("+heads+") VALUES ("+placestr+")")
  data_capacitor = mylistv

  cursor.execute(duplicate_check)
  rows = cursor.fetchall()
  for row in rows:
      for col in row:
          if col == value['display_value']: 
              cursor.execute(replace_capacitor, data_capacitor)
          else:
              cursor.execute(add_capacitor, data_capacitor)
  emp_no = cursor.lastrowid

  cnx.commit()
  time.sleep(1)
  ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you should be using [`INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html). Then, instead of selecting and re-processing each row of the table, you merely insert that data with one call to [`cursor.execute`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#id18), and let the MySQL engine handle the updates when there is a duplicate key:

```
heads = ','.join(str(i) for i in mylisth)
placelst = ['%s' for i in mylisth]
placestr = ','.join(str(i) for i in placelst)

replacestr = ', '.join(['{}=%s'.format(h) for h in mylisth])
sql = """INSERT INTO capacitors ({heads}) VALUES ({placestr})
         ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE {replacestr}""".format(
         heads=heads, placestr=placestr,
         replacestr=replacestr)

for data_capacitor in larger_loop:
    args = data_capacitor*2
    cursor.execute(sql, args)
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions!  I'm just a little confused  by one aspect.  This code segment runs in a for loop in the larger script.  Each loop, the mylistv variable is updated with a new row of data from the website.  So when the data_capacitor variable is created, it is itself a single row of data.  When you talk about data_capacitors (plural) I'm not sure what you mean by *all* of the data that I'm inserting.  As far as each loop is concerned, data_capacitor is all of the data I'm inserting

Comment: Ah, in that case, you can simply make `args = data_capacitor*2` and call `cursor.execute(sql, args)`. I've update the code to show what I mean.

Comment: I've ultimately ended up changing my code a little bit.  What was your suggestion before you edited your answer?  I know you looped something to the effect of -->   for data_capacitor in data_capacitors…. What did the code look like again?

Comment: Here's a direct [link to the old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/c9ea280e-ce1b-45b8-84d2-5c51ef070551/view-source). You can also find it by clicking on the "edited ... days ago" link located in the center, below the answer, but above the comments.

Comment: Thanks!  That looks like exactly what I need